# How to Pass multiple functions defined in local server to remote server using ssh and typeset

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to pass multiple fuctions which are defined in local server(myscript.sh) to remote server using ssh and typeset, I know how to pass a single fuction using typeset, I was wondering if we can pass multiple fuctions definitions using ssh and typeset.

```
getIPAddress()
        {       
                ip_address=$(hostname -i)
                echo $ip_address
        } 
getMachineHostName()
        {
                machine_name=$(hostname -s)
                echo $machine_name
                echo "The IP is" $(getIPAddress)
                
        } 
#This only passes the getMachineHostName fuction but not the getIPAddress fuction to ssh
ssh user@remote "$(typeset -f getMachineHostName); getMachineHostName"
```

Comment: try: `help export`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put only the definition of one function in the string sent to the remote host. Why do you think the other function would magically appear as well?

You need to define **all** functions before you can use them:

```
ssh user@remote "$(typeset -f getMachineHostName); $(typeset -f getIPAddress); getMachineHostName"
```

Comment: Thank you @user1934428 for your help, I was struggling with the correct syntax for passing the other function.

Comment: The syntax is the same as for the first function. And to tell you a secret: If you one day need to pass a third function, the syntax would be the same again....

Comment: Thank you @user1934428, I am new to shell scripting, and I am extremely grateful for your feedback and help. I apologize for asking the silly question. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: It's also possible to transmit them in one statement: `$(typeset -f getIPAddress getMachineHostName); getMachineHostName`